# SOQL for Loops giving an error: Too many query rows

Tags: soql

I have the code below:

```
Integer counter = 0;
for(Account[] records: [SELECT Id FROM Account]) {
    counter += records.size();
}
```

While executing this anonymous code, I am getting an error:

```
Error on line 36, column 1: System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001
Class.Database.QueryLocatorChunkIterator.next: line 36, column 1
External entry point
AnonymousBlock: line 11, column 1
23:03:00.757 (3757182588)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[11]|Rows:50001
```

I checked the documentation, and I found that SOQL for loops **retrieve all sObjects**, using efficient chunking with calls to the query and queryMore methods of the SOAP API.

There are 9 million records in Account object, so how can I use SOQL for-loop to iterate over all the accounts? Or am I missing something?

And the most important question: is it possible to query more than 50000 records in a synchronous transaction?

Comment: The most you can query via any approach in apex code is 50000 records PER TRANSACTION. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm

Comment: I was asked a question, and I knew that it's not possible to query more than 50000 records in a synchronous transaction. But he said that using querymore, it's possible. And I was like seriously?

Comment: Not in a single transaction. You would have to have this split into multiple transactions from an external system (e.g. the browser) or using a sequence of async transactions. On the latter, you can process up to 50000000 (50 million) records in a batch, though that's not doing it via a single transaction of course. Even though [COUNT queries](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_soql_count_limits.htm) changed, this still faces limits - typically CPU - if there are WHERE conditions that must be at least partially handled in memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [SOQL for loop](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm) is focused on avoiding heap space issues, as that page says:

> Developers should always use a SOQL for loop to process query results that return many records, to avoid the limit on heap size.

This is important when you are querying a lot of large records.

The SOQL for loop structure does not allow you to circumvent the hard limit of 50000 records queried (across all SOSL/SOQL) in a transaction, as covered in the [Apex Governor Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm) documentation.

Since all you want to do here is perform a COUNT, you could instead consider using the COUNT query. This was [updated back in Summer '18](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_soql_count_limits.htm) to reduce the number of query row limits consumed. Even so, you can find that COUNT queries fail with timeouts or because they are not selective enough.

If you have a hard requirement to count the number of Account records in your system, you could hold the count in a separate object and look to maintain this count via logic in the Account trigger (incrementing on insert/undelete, decrementing on delete). The initial calculation could be handled via a Batch, since these are able to process up to 50000000 rows (and your count is less than that limit at the moment).